# create and preview new message in IBM lotus notes using java

Tags: java, html, spring, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In my web application created with spring mvc, I am having a feature like, i am having a page with a message and a send hyperlink, on clicking the send link it should open a ibm lotus notes new message window, with the message copied along with to, cc, subject details dynamically like as shown in the picture.

**Note:** The lotus notes will be always running and logined within all the client systems.

I have tried to achieve this first by using **[mailto: HTML e-mail link](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm)** feature, but got worked only in chrome and firefox, in IE it failed

Is there any way to achieve this by using java

My code is as given below

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ubyj3q7/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller"> 
    <b>Message :</b> {{message}}
    <br>
    <a href="mailto:manu?cc=jacob&amp;subject=Test%20Mail&amp;body={{message}}">Send</a>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'sample sample sample test message';
});
```

**Main Page Screen**

[image]

Lotus notes new message when clicking the send hyperlink

[image]

Comment: mailto: requires that the web bro0wser is configured with a default mail application. It sounds like on your test system only Chrome and Firefox have that setup.
But you should not rely on mailto: unless you have full control of the web browsers.

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson can we achieve this through java

Comment: The language does not really matter, it is the capabilities of the platform that matters.
A good and secure browser should not be able to access local resources. I think you may want to think through your solution a littl ebit first.

Comment: There is an OLE API for Lotus Notes that can drive the client operations, but AFAIK nobody has built a Java interface that can call this API. It would not be as easy task. But FYI, the two root classes for the OLE API are Notes.NotesUIWorkspace and Notes.NotesSession - and be very careful not to confuse the latter with Lotus.NotesSession, because that is a COM API and it does not include any of the capabilities for driving the Notes UI that the OLE API does.

Answer (score 0):

I would never build a web application that in any way relies on specific client software being installed and/or running locally.
What I would do is to either make a call to iNotes in the browser, or simply create a mail form on the web where the user fill out the recipients and write the message. That page upon submission would call a Lotusscript, Java or XPages agent on the server that will create the actual email and send it.

I have a class for creating mail notification, you can use that as a starting point if you like.

http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/